# Running a file through a function

Tags: python, file, function, anagram

I'm trying to create a new file of rows of anagrams from a current file.

```
def Ana(str1, str2):
    str1_list = list(str1)
    str1_list.sort()
    str2_list = list(str2)
    str2_list.sort()
    return (str1_list == str2_list)

newerfile=open("ana.txt","w")
f = open("words.txt")
for word in f:
    s = str(word)
    for word2 in f:
        if word!=word2:
            if Ana(word, word2) is True:
                s += (' ') + str(word2)

if s!=str(word):
    newerfile.write(s)
```

The above is my current code, but all it gives me is an empty file. After experimenting a bit, I believe the problem is at the 4th last line - "if isAnagram(word, word2) if True:"

The function is not working for the file I have. I've tried a more basic version of the code to test the entire file against one word. Since the words 'was' and 'saw' are in the file, I should be getting those, but nothing is being printed.

```
y = 'was'
for line in open('real_words.txt'):
    if isAnagram(line,'was') is True:
        y += (' ') + str(line)
print(y)
```

The function is working fine when I provide a list of words, but not for a file. Any help is appreciated.

Also is there any way to delete the word and all anagrams from the file if function returns true?

Comment: Is `Ana` the `isAnagram` function you are referring to? By the way, your first piece of code says `if isAnagram() if True`, while your second piece of code says `if isAnagram() is True`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Ana and isAnagram are the same, and the is and if are typos when I was rewritting the code here.

Comment: how would I be able to get 2 list of the same words of the file?

Comment: would "for word and word2 in "file":" work?

Comment: When you do `for word in f` this is an iterator, that is, it will be exhausted after the first iteration of the inner loop. If you want to test all combinations of words, copy them to a list first, or use `itertools.product`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you explain it in English?

Comment: I have a file of words. I need to find all possible anagrams of every word in the file and then transfer a line for each anagram group into a new file

Comment: Are you trying to generate all anagrams for each word in the file regardless of whether or not they appear in the file, or are you just looking to remove words that have an anagram already included?

Comment: I'm trying to find the anagrams present in the old file and transfer them to a new file while deleting them from the old file.

Comment: When writing words with an anagram to your new file, do you care about preserving order? EG if your input file has "dog", "cat", "god", "tac", "ogd", do you need those to be output in the same interleaved order?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I'll need one line with all anagrams of cat, then the next line should be all anagrams of dog. If you read the given code (despite the errors), you should be able to understand that.

Answer (score 2):

The best data structure for this is a dict of lists, where the sorted version of each string is the key. Each word that shares that sorted version will go into the list. After generating that, keys with only one word go into the file for words with no anagrams, while keys with multiple words go into the anagrams file.

```
from collections import defaultdict
words_by_sorted = defaultdict(list)
f = open("words.txt")
for line in f:
    word = line.strip() # remove the newline
    sorted_key = tuple(sorted(word))
    words_by_sorted[sorted_key].append(word)
f.close()
unanagrammed = open("unanagrammed.txt", "w")
anagrammed = open("anagrammed.txt", "w")
for words in words_by_sorted.itervalues():
    if len(words) == 1:
        unanagrammed.write(words[0] + '\n')
    else:
        anagrammed.write(' '.join(words) + '\n')
unanagrammed.close()
anagrammed.close()
```

This does not maintain order in either file. If you need to do that, you could maintain a list of the sorted keys in the order you first saw them, or use an ordered dict (and explicitly create the lists as needed rather than use a `defaultdict`) if you're on 2.7.

It also creates two files - you can't really "delete them from the old file", but you could overwrite it if you like. This approach lets you examine your output more closely before removing the input.

It would also be a good practice to use `with` statements for opening the files, but your base code uses raw `open` so I stuck with that.

Comment: That's actually much nicer (and faster) than my solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming `words.txt` is a file with one word per line, and you are trying to find all pairs of anagrams of those words and print them to a second file, one pair per line.)

There seem to be two problems with your code:

1. When you do `for word in f` you are using an iterator, and with `for word2 in f` you use *the same* iterator, i.e., that iterator will be exhausted after the first iteration of the loop!
2. You seem to write to file only after the loop has completed, but `s` will always hold just the last pair of words, so you would write just that pair to the file. (Could just be a problem with indentation.)

For getting all the combinations of two words, it would be best to use `itertools.combinations`, somewhat like this (untested, kind of pseudo-code):

```
words = infile.read().splitlines()
for w1, w2 in itertools.combinations(words, 2):
     if isAnagram(w1, w2):
          outfile.write("%s %s" % (w1, w2))
```

However, this will write just one *pair* of anagrams per line. If you want to write entire *groups* into one line, I guess you will need two loops, like in your code. Just remember not to use the same iterator for both loops, e.g. put the contents of the filt into a list first, and then use that list for the loops.

You could also use a list comprehension for this:

```
words = infile.read().splitlines()
for w1 in words:
    outfile.write(" ".join(w2 for w2 in words if isAnagram(w1, w2)))
```

(Note that this still is not perfect, as the lines will be repeated, once for each word in the group. But I'm sure you can figure out the rest by yourself.)